# /summon not working for json text

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried the command:

```
/summon Armor_Stand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:{"text":"hi","color":"aqua"}}
```

But all the time it showed me "Armor Stand" as the nametag. So is there any way I can fix this error and get a coloured nametag? I'm using Minecraft 1.10.2.

Comment: Data tags are case sensitive, so that is probably your only problem.  Use `CustomName` instead of `customname`

Comment: I tried that tooo

Answer (score 3):

> `/summon armorstand ~ ~1 ~ {customname:{"text":"hi","color":"aqua}}`

Unless you're using the latest snapshot (in which case it's `armor_stand`), the name of an armor stand is `ArmorStand`, case sensitive. NBTags are also case sensitive: it's `CustomName` rather than `customname`.

You'll need to add a `CustomNameVisible:1b` tag to have the name show up. You'd also need to end the quotation mark at the end of `"aqua`, and escape the whole JSON part, which would end up with a command like this:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"{\"text\":\"hi\",\"color\":\"aqua\"}",CustomNameVisible:1}
```

*2019 edit: As of 1.13, `CustomName`s do now support JSON and the above command will work (changing ID to `armor_stand`). The information below should be ignored unless you're still on older versions.*

**However**, the main problem is that `CustomName`'s don't yet support JSON.

If you use a third party tool (such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) or [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit-unified.net/)) you could put the section sign (§) followed by a [formatting code](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes) before the name to achieve the colour/effect you want. The command (which you cannot input directly into Minecraft) would look like:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"§bhi",CustomNameVisible:1}
```

Comment: Ok now i get it. Thx for your interest

Comment: And this is  why I didn't provide a full answer.  You can assign the armor stand to a team in order to color the name, though.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes i usually use tab while typing commands

Comment: "the latest snapshot" is now a three-year-old version, and Minecraft 1.13 and newer version do support JSON in `CustomName`. Perhaps you should update this answer.